# Latex tikzpicture add labels to hierarchy branches

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have a hierarchy:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=7cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm}, 
level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}, align = flush center]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw,rectangle]

    \node {Root}
        [style=edge from parent fork down]
        child { 
            node {1} 
            child {node {1.1} 
                child {node {1.1.1} }
                child {node {1.1.2} }
                child {node {1.1.3} }
                }
            child {node {1.2}}
            child {node {1.3}}
        }
        child { 
            node {2} 
            child {node {2.1}}
            child {node {2.2} 
                child {node {2.2.1} }
                child {node {2.2.2} }
                child {node {2.2.3} }
                }
            child {node {2.3}}
        }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture} 
}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I was wondering, how would I change my latex so that there are labels on some branches of the figure? So for example, the word 'left' would be on the branch between the 'Root' and '1' and the word 'right' would be on the branch between the 'Root' and '2'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `edge from parent node`. Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=7cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm}, 
level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}, align = flush center]
\tikzset{every node/.append style={draw,rectangle}}

    \node {Root}
        [style=edge from parent fork down]
        child { 
            node {1}    
            child {node {1.1} 
                child {node {1.1.1} }
                child {node {1.1.2} }
                child {node {1.1.3} }
                }
            child {node {1.2}}
            child {node {1.3}}
        edge from parent node[pos=0.25,above,draw=none]{left}%<-added
        } 
        child { 
            node {2} 
            child {node {2.1}}
            child {node {2.2} 
                child {node {2.2.1} }
                child {node {2.2.2} }
                child {node {2.2.3} }
                }
            child {node {2.3}}
        edge from parent node[pos=0.25,above,draw=none]{right}%<-added
        }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

With forest this enterprise becomes arguably more straightforward.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=south,draw,s sep=2em},
forked edges
[Root
 [1,edge label={node[pos=0.35,above]{left}}
  [1.1
   [1.1.1]
   [1.1.2]
   [1.1.3]
  ]
  [1.2] 
  [1.3] 
 ]
 [2,edge label={node[pos=0.35,above]{right}}
  [2.1]
  [2.2
   [2.2.1]
   [2.2.2]
   [2.2.3]
  ] 
  [2.3] 
 ]
] 
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]